# can't go back because of intent launching in background android

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is my activity Mod_1_1_b. on startup, this activity takes user to Mod_1_1_c after 3 sec,
Mod_1_1_b has a button for going to some other activity (main) but whenever i press that button, it first takes me to main activity and then immediately launches Mod_1_1_c. i have tried calling finish(); but not working, looks like the intent already launches in background.

```
package com.example.abc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

public class Mod_1_1_b extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mod_1_1_b);

        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer
                .create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yolo); // -<
        mp1.start();
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent startActivity = new Intent(Mod_1_1_b.this,
                        Mod_1_1_c.class);// -<
                startActivity(startActivity);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_to_left_1,
                        R.anim.slide_right_to_left_2);
                finish();
            }

        }, 3000L);

    }

    public void back(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mod_1_1AtoZ.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_to_right_1,
                R.anim.slide_left_to_right_2);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="290dip"
        android:layout_height="290dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/b_tile" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="back"
        android:text="Back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is the button located post the code for it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin i have just posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it first takes me to main activity and then immediately launches Mod_1_1_c
```

That is because you set your handler to execute in 3 seconds thus after you press that button it will change the activity but it will still execute your handler and change to activity `Mod_1_1_c`

**solution:**

In you button `back` you need to cancel your handler to stop it executing after you changed activity.

**sample:**

```
public void back(View view) {
    timeoutHandler.removeCallbacks(your_runnable);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mod_1_1AtoZ.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_to_right_1,
            R.anim.slide_left_to_right_2);
    finish();
}
```

Make sure that your `Runnable` and `Handler` has global instance of it.

EDIT:

```
public class Mod_1_1_b extends Activity {


    Handler mHandler; //global instance
    Runnable your_runnable; //global instance

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mod_1_1_b);

        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer
                .create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yolo); // -<
        mp1.start();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        your_runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent startActivity = new Intent(Mod_1_1_b.this,
                        Mod_1_1_c.class);// -<
                startActivity(startActivity);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_to_left_1,
                        R.anim.slide_right_to_left_2);
                finish();
            }

        };

        mHandler.postDelayed(your_runnable , 3000L);

    }

    public void back(View view) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(your_runnable);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mod_1_1AtoZ.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_to_right_1,
                R.anim.slide_left_to_right_2);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: it's difficult to understand your answer. please post the edited question instead, that would be much easier to understand. and will i be able to use timer in your code?

Comment: @JRE.exe see edit above. if you press it before 3 second it will change activity to `Mod_1_1AtoZ` and wont change activity after. But by default it will change activity in 3 seconds

Comment: @JRE.exe change it to `mHandler `

Comment: you can edit the question to make it helpful or easily understandable